# MySQL error when ran through PHP, but not in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have checked for an answer to this question on here, but can't seem to find it. Other questions have been about not returning results, but mine throws an SQL error.

I have this query I am running through PHP:

```
SELECT WISH.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.CUST_LNAME, CUSTOMER.CUST_FNAME, 
       WISH.ITEM_ID, ITEM.ITEM_NAME, WISH.WISH_NOTES, 
       WISH.WISH_ADDED, WISH.WISH_DELETED
FROM WISH
LEFT JOIN ITEM ON WISH.ITEM_ID = ITEM.ITEM_ID
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER ON WISH.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER.CUST_ID
WHERE WISH.CUST_ID != -1 AND CUSTOMER.CUST_FNAME LIKE '%k%' 
ORDER BY ITEM.ITEM_DELETED ASC 
LIMIT 0, 15
```

When I run this in PHP, it gives the following error: Unknown column 'CUSTOMER.CUST_FNAME' in 'where clause. But when I run it directly through MySQL (I ran it through a program connected to the database) it returns the results that I want without error.

It might be something obvious, but I need another set of eyes to help figure it out.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:** I have a file that is dynamically creating this query with variables given through a GET url. I am escaping these variables with mysql_real_escape_string(), and then putting them in their places, and running the query. The problem seems to be with the dynamic nature of the query; if I copy and paste the query after it is put together, put it into my file as a string and run it, it works fine. I tried to cast the dynamic query to a string once it was put together, but it did not fix the problem. Any thoughts?

UPDATE 2: I go and look at the application today to try to debug the problem again and it is suddenly working, and I don't know what it would be that would have made it work - because I have not done anything except trying to clean up the code in the file I am running...Thanks for everyone's help though!

Comment: Make sure you are connected the right database?  Only thing I can think of that changes between the two.

Comment: @mazzzzz: I am sure that it is connected, I have a database class that keeps the connection across my application and the query runs fine through php if I remove that part of the where clause.

Comment: @bensiu: As in left or right? Maybe I should - and I might later, but it should still run the query with it the way it is...

Comment: @bensiu: I updated the question with left joins, and did the same in my code.

Comment: Left join is not right unless you can have a wish with no item/customer. INNER JOIN is probably the way to go. This would be the same as JOIN, so not sure why that's a problem.

Comment: Try removing the where clause and see if you get a different error

Comment: I think you should try `SELECT * FROM WISH`, `SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER`, `SELECT * FROM ITEM` seperately to see if you get errors.

Comment: @therealsix: Okay, I will change the join back - I am still not used to using joins, it is one thing that I can't completely grasp with SQL.

Comment: About my problem: I moved the query to a different file to run, and it ran just fine - so maybe it is something about a part of the PHP file I am running it in?

Comment: Do you ever connect to a different DB on that same server? You are (were) probably changing databases without realizing. see mysql_select_db()

Answer (score 0):

If it was a connection error, you would recieve a PHP error, because it's a MySQL error, I can assume that you are have a connection resource, however, not database is selected, make sure:
`mysql_select_database($dbname, $conn)` is pointing at the right database.
if that fails, you can try connecting to the correct database using the query itself

```
[Database].[table].[field]
```

Try running a small queries at first to see what the problem is exactly, espacially for the field which gives you the error.

Eventually you'll see it was a silly mistake.

Good Luck!

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with not having a database selected, as it works if I remove the "CUSTOMER.CUST_FNAME LIKE '%k%'" part of the where clause. I also moved the query to a different file to run, and it executed perfectly fine - but I need it to run in the file it was originally in, so I will have to figure that out.